# Magento 2: Adding an additional filter in categories / products in category

Tags: magento2, category-products

[image]Is there any way to add a custom attirbute in here? (See picture). I know the file is in

> /vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/grid/extended.phtml

But I have no idea how to add ?

Answer (score 1):

Try following way:

> SR/Stackexchange/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" type="SR\Stackexchange\Block\Catalog\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"/>
</config>
```

> SR/Stackexchange/Block/Catalog/Adminhtml/Category/Tab/Product.php

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Block\Catalog\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{
    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $grid = parent::_prepareCollection();

        $collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->joinTable(
            'cataloginventory_stock_status',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            ["stock_status" => "stock_status"],
            null ,
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        if ($this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->clear();
        }
        return $grid;
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumn('stock_status', ['header' => __('Stock Status'), 'index' => 'stock_status']);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have follow your code but it is not working